# How to stop Direct3D 11 from stretching fullscreen to monitor size?

Tags: c++, windows, direct3d, direct3d11

I am trying to make my Direct3D window fullscreen, with an 800x600 resolution. However, everything I try makes the screen stretch to cover the entire monitor, instead of just taking up an 800x600 area with black bars on the sides. The cursor is also stretched.

I create my swap chain with this DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC:

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd{};
sd.BufferDesc.Width = 0;
sd.BufferDesc.Height = 0;
sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0;
sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 0;
sd.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
sd.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
sd.BufferCount = 1;
sd.OutputWindow = hWnd;
sd.Windowed = TRUE;
sd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
sd.Flags = 0;
```

Then I set the screen resolution using this code:

```
DEVMODEW devMode{};
devMode.dmSize = sizeof(devMode);
devMode.dmPelsWidth = width;
devMode.dmPelsHeight = height;
devMode.dmFields = DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_PELSWIDTH;
LONG res = ChangeDisplaySettingsW(&devMode, CDS_FULLSCREEN);
```

Finally I set the swap chain to be fullscreen:

```
HRESULT hr = swap->SetFullscreenState(on, nullptr);
```

Also, in my window procedure I call this whenever WM_SIZE is received:

```
swapChain.reset(); // Destroy swap chain
context->ClearState();
if (FAILED(swap->ResizeBuffers(0, 0, 0, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0))) throw Exception("Failed to resize buffers");
swapChain.emplace(swap.Get(), device.Get(), context.Get(), hWnd); // Recreate swap chain
```

I have tried using DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH in both the DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC and the ResizeBuffers, as well as calling [IDXGISwapChain::ResizeTarget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiswapchain-resizetarget) with my desired size, but I still get the same problem.

Comment: Try setting a viewport to the desired size, instead of the whole swapchain

Comment: I don't know Direct3D, but wouldn't it *set your monitor size to* 800x600? That's normally how fullscreen works.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes How would I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure (I know D3D12, but they're quite different), but I believe it's [`RSSetViewports`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-rssetviewports)

Comment: Take a look at this [blog series](https://walbourn.github.io/care-and-feeding-of-modern-swapchains/)